# How do I get jQuery to recognise separate values

Tags: jquery

I have a got some jQuery working to make a simple search / filter feature. The feature allows a user to type in the text field and it in turn shows only the list items which have those characters i.e. type 'red' it shows all list items with 'red' in it.

My problem is that it only works for the exact input i.e. if type in 'red blue', it will only find 'red blue', not 'blue red'or other 'red' items.

Could anyone help in a solution to my problem?

Here's my code:

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.filterlist>li').show();
  } else {
    $('.filterlist>li').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="box" type="text" placeholder="Search">

<ul class="filterlist" style="list-style:none;">
  <li>red</li>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>red blue</li>
  <li>blue red</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: exactly it works fine @JasonF

Comment: Have you tried to split the string by word boundary and process each word separately, collating the results? Also, this is a fairly common use case for an [autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: it works only if you put in the exact term. If you type in 'red blue', I would like it to show 'ALL' items with 'red' and 'blue' in it.

Comment: Have you seen the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.filterlist>li').show();
  } else {
    var subValues = valThis.trim().split(' ');

    $('.filterlist>li').each(function () {
      var node = $(this);
      var text = node.text().toLowerCase();

      if (subValues.some(function (word) {
        return text.indexOf(word) !== -1;
      })) {
        node.show();
      }
      else {
        node.hide();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0xjwapdf/

As suggested in the comments, we split the search terms into separate words, and then search for each of those words.

Comment: Took your comment onboard and was busy trying out split() when your example popped up. Works great, but if you type 'red' then space, it shows all until you type the next word, but otherwise it pretty much is what I am looking. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JasonF eww, you're right! I added a trim call to get rid of those extraneous checks, I'm sure you've figured that out by now though :)

Comment: no did not add in the trim yet, but thanks for that, your help is hugely appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.filterlist>li').show();
  } else {
    var test = valThis.split(" ");
    if(test.length >1) {
        console.log("More then one word")
        $('.filterlist>li').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            $.each(test, function( index, value ) {
                  (text.indexOf(value) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
            });

        });
    }else{
        $('.filterlist>li').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
        });
    }
  };
})
```

Updated jQuery if more then one word came we will check with each word in the text box.